# How to read properties file in java

Tags: java

I want write a java program

**Problem:**

I have property file, in the property file contains

```
range="1,5,35-50,100"
```

I should get the input as range from command prompt or JSP and print out message likes `this is a range` or `this is not a range`

let us consider following I/O should be looks like

```
Input:1
Output:this is a range

Input:2
Output:this is not a range

Input:37
Output:this is a range

Input:60
Output:this is not a range

Input:100
Output:this is a range
```

can anybody help me, advance in thanks

Comment: Accept answers to your questions by clicking the "check" by the correct solution.  19 questions with no accepted answers is not a good way to encourage people to help you...

Answer (score 1):

You can read the property file values, store them in a DataStructure lets say Array and use `contains` method to check if the value read from command line is contained in the array or not. Let me know in case you need any help in writing code for this or you are stuck anywhere.

Comment: i have only property file. and output will be looks likes as i was mentioned, i don't know how to write a program. so please give ur idea/logic

Comment: @Ganesamoorthy - No, people aren't going to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String bundle = "your properties file name without .properties";
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundle);
String range = rb.getString("range");
```