# How to use properties file in my Eclipse project without using any hard code in calling java file?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read properties file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295084/how-to-read-properties-file-in-java)

I have a 'MyProp.properties' file having key-values like:

```
browser = Firefox
baseURL = http:\\www.google.com
user = student
```

The above key-value pairs I want to use in my project

How can I achieve that?
I am new to JAVA, please guide me through

Comment: Do you want to `find` the properties file automatically without hardcoding?

Answer (score 1):

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

//get the property value and print it out
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("browser"));
```

You could have spent some time in google/stackoverflow before throwing questions. .

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to this forum so learning the dynamics. Thanks for help :)

Comment: No problem,welcome to the group,You may accept the answer if it solve your problem